# Printing out HTML via an Ajax-Request that is having errors stops further JS from working

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

I made a little experiment with my site. I have a site, that is empty. Then it makes an AJAX-Request to a php file where a random website is being gathered. The website is being gathered by using multiple random words, doing a search request with them to google and select a random result. Then with curl I follow that result and print out the contents, and set the in my ajax-request into my html. Then, normally the next page should be gathered.

However, the problem is, that after a website loaded, the website itself has JavaScript errors (probably because of paths or sth?)

How would I fix this? This is my code. As I said, it's just an experiment, so I'm not using Prototypes, classes, tests, comments or whatever, just plain stupid writing the code down

```
<section id="content">
</section>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.0.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        newSite();

        function newSite()
        {
            $.ajax({
                url: 'sites.php',
                dataType: 'html'
            }).done(function(data) {
                $('#content').html(data);
                $('#content').scrollTop(300);

                newSite();
            });
        }
    });
</script>
```

And this is where I get the site contents and print them out in the php file (I'm not showing the full code here, because there is stuff you don't need)

```
$ch = curl_init();

// set URL and other appropriate options
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, $userAgent);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $final);

$content = curl_exec($ch);

echo $content;
```

`$final` is the URL of the google result. Any ideas?

Comment: have you actually checked the contents of `$content` for beeing not empty?

Comment: Yes. They aren't empty. I'm seeing a webpage, so everything is working. But after setting the content I want to do a new request, but nothing happens anymore after `$('#content').html(data);` when there is an error

Comment: what says `console.log(data)`? Sorry for those beginner questions but I'm trying to pin down where it breaks

Comment: `console.log(data)` simply prints out the whole HTML content of the website I just gathered.

Comment: have you tried capturing errors with `window.onerror`? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/GlobalEventHandlers/onerror

Comment: Why don't you send the url instead of the content ? As you've guessed, the content of the 1rst page is not enough, there's external dependencies.

Comment: I think I know what the error is. The JavaScript of the website is tried to being executed and therefore the error comes. Wouldn't it be enough If I would remove all script tags with PHP before printing out the HTML for the Ajax-Request?

Comment: @Ilya - What do you mean by sending the URL?

Comment: My guess would be to strip html content you don't need, javascript, styles, everything inside `<head>` and so on.

Comment: @Musterknabe I'll put it in an answer, it's a bit too long for a comment.

Comment: @Soundz - Yeah, that's what I just did. Removed all JS. Now it works fine!

Comment: @Ilya - You don't need to anymore ( just if you want). I fixed the issue by removing all script tags from the site before printing it out

Comment: @Musterknabe I see. If it's an experiment it's ok to break some parts (or all) of the websites I guess.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to load a random website, you can't just insert the first page in your own document, the site often has other files to load with some relative path that won't work in your page (JS, images,...).

You can strip the JS content, but some sites will break without it, and even if they doesn't you could still be missing some parts.

Instead of sending the content, you could send the URL from your PHP code and use `window.open` to display the target website (and `window.close` to close the previous one).

For instance:

```
var windowRef = window.open(url, name);
```

Usually the window is opened in a new tab. If `name` is not empty, the window will reuse the tab opened with the same `name` instead of opening another.

Comment: Wouldn't that mean though that I can only open one page? Or can I continue my script? Because I want to open always a new website

Comment: You can open several pages like you're doing now, you just have to close (or reuse) the previous one. `window.open` gives you an id, and the 2nd parameter allows to reuse a tab.

Comment: Ah okay, but that would mean that a new tab would open right? I would like it to always have on the current tab. Also, I see another problem with that. What if the site I'm visiting has a "Do you really want to leave the site?" alert window? Wouldn't that mean I would not be possible to open a new tab until the alert window is closed?

Comment: It's a new window (usually new tab), unless a window with that name already exists. Not sure about the alert, do you know any site which does that on its first page ?

Comment: Since I'm gathering random websites that could happen. But scam sites for example are doing this quite often

Comment: Well, how to deal with that (scam sites for instance) depends on your goals (the nature of your "experiment"). If it's mainly for knowledge, it's good to know how `window.open` works, it's quite useful to integrate other sites or services, such as Google Maps.